# Is being in the same ideal class transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Two nonzero ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ in a Dedekind domain are in the same ideal class if there exist nonzero elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x \mathfrak{a} = y \mathfrak{b}$.

My attempt at showing the relation "being in the same ideal class" is transitive:

Let $x \mathfrak{a} = y \mathfrak{b}$ and let $y' \mathfrak{b} = z \mathfrak{c}$. Pick $b_0 \in R$ such that $b_0 R \subset y \mathfrak{b}$ and $b_0 R \subset y' \mathfrak{b}$. Then, there exists a unique ideals $\mathfrak{r}$ and $\mathfrak{r'}$ such that $b_0 R = y \mathfrak{b} \mathfrak{r} = y'\mathfrak{b} \mathfrak{r'}$. So $b_0y \mathfrak{b} = b_0 y' \mathfrak{b}$ and $b_0 x \mathfrak{a} = b_0 z \mathfrak{c}$.

The possible problems I can see here are the assumption that there exists a nonzero $b_0$ that generates the prime ideal that's contained in these ideals, and how to get from $b_0 R = y \mathfrak{b} \mathfrak{r} = y'\mathfrak{b} \mathfrak{r'}$ to $b_0y \mathfrak{b} = b_0 y' \mathfrak{b}$, and I'm definitely grasping at straws on the last one. Is the ideal class not transitive in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a domain is a commutative ring without zero divisors:

$$ x \mathfrak{a} = y \mathfrak{b} \\
   z \mathfrak{b} = w \mathfrak{c} 
$$

gives us:

$$ (xz) \mathfrak{a} = (yw) \mathfrak{c} $$

and nonzeroness of $xz,yw$ is clear.